# how to get specific column names from a pandas DF that satisfies a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data as follow:

```
col1  col2  col3   col4  col5     
 0     1     0      1     0     
 1     1     0      0     1     
 1     1     1      0     1
```

I want it as below:-

```
  col1  col2  col3   col4  col5     col6
  0     1     0      1     0     col2,col4
  1     1     0      0     1     col2,col4,col5
  1     1     1      0     1     col1,col2,col3,col5
```

Whereever the value is 1, the column name should be appended in col 6. I tried idx.max(), however its not working  may be because there are more than one column which satisfies the condition. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a matrix multiplication here:

```
(df @ (df.columns + ',')).str[:-1]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5                 col6
0     0     1     0     1     0            col2,col4
1     1     1     0     0     1       col1,col2,col5
2     1     1     1     0     1  col1,col2,col3,col5
```

Comment: I have 200000 records & about 60 columns. Matrix multiplication could be very time consuming. Is there any other way?

Comment: `200000 x 60` is not that many :-), took less than 1 second on my computer.

Comment: would it give me the expected output?? I also want to assign it to a new df,  I guess it shud be new_df=(df @ (df.columns + ',')).str[:-1].....is this okay?

Comment: no, you do `df['col6'] = (df @ ...).str[-1]`. Then your df looks like the expected output. if you want a new dataframe, you can use `assign`: `new_df = df.assing(col_name=(df @ ...).str[-1]`

Comment: getting this error    :- TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'DataFrame' and 'Index'